# Can't pass files from +page.svelte to +page.server.ts in a form

Tags: forms, svelte, sveltekit

Here we have a form, we are trying to post the form with uploaded files to our API/server. However, the data posts fine. When I read the request on the backend I can see the other form inputs but the files array shows the indexes just not the contents.

In addition when I dump the formData to the console I can see the File array.

I have built a custom file input, its pretty simple in reality. I will share the 3 files which are involved here. The file uploader, `+page.svelte` & `+page.server.ts`

```html
<!-- Fileuploader.svelte -->
<script lang="ts">
    import Icon from '@iconify/svelte';

    let selectedFiles = [];
    let uploading = false;
    let errorMessage = '';
  
    const maxFiles = 20;
  
    const handleFileInputChange = (event, input: HTMLInputElement) => {
      const files = event.target.files;
  
      if (files.length + selectedFiles.length > maxFiles) {
        errorMessage = `You can select a maximum of ${maxFiles} images.`;
        return;
      }
  
      errorMessage = '';
      uploading = true;
  
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const file = files[i];
        if (file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
          selectedFiles = [...selectedFiles, file as File];
        }
      }

      uploading = false;
    };
  
    const removeFile = (index) => {
      selectedFiles = selectedFiles.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
    };
</script>

<input
      type="file"
      accept="image/*"
      multiple
      name="photos"
      class="hidden"
      id="fileInput"
      on:change={handleFileInputChange}
    />
```

```html
<!-- +page.svelte -->
<script>
... rest of file
    export let form: ActionData;
    export let data: PageData;

    let selectedFiles = [];
</script>
<form id="listingForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" use:enhance>
   <FilePicker bind:selectedFiles />
   
... Rest of the form & submit button
</form>
```

```js
// +page.server.ts
export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request, locals, cookies, url }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();

        const formData = new FormData(); // Create a new FormData object
        
        formData.append('title', data.get('title'));

        const fileArr = data.getAll('photos');
        for (const file of fileArr) {
            formData.append('photos', file);
        }

        const itemResponse = await authClient('/item/create', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                ... Cookies
            },
            data: formData
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
};
```

I just cannot seem to get it working. I have tried for hours.

Comment: "It is the files which are the problem." says nothing